# spritesheet animation

Tags: javascript, json, animation, sprite-sheet

I'm trying to get a script to run but I'm having a little trouble. I've only used javascript once before, but now i have to make a character animation walk back and forth on a web page and continue until the page is closed.  My debugger says there is a reference error on line 57, but i'm sure thats not the only problem.  If anyone could take a look at the code and see if anything pops out at them, I would be grateful.

```
goog.provide('mysprites');


goog.require('lime');
goog.require('lime.Director');
goog.require('lime.Layer');
goog.require('lime.Sprite');
goog.require('lime.fill.Frame');
goog.require('lime.animation.KeyframeAnimation');
goog.require('lime.animation.MoveBy');
goog.require('lime.SpriteSheet');
goog.require('lime.animation.MoveTo');
goog.require('lime.animation.Sequence');
goog.require('lime.animation.Loop');
goog.require('lime.animation.Delay');
goog.require('lime.parser.JSON');
goog.require('lime.ASSETS.spaceman.json');


mysprites.WIDTH = 600;
mysprites.HEIGHT = 400;


mysprites.start = function() {

//director
mysprites.director = new lime.Director(document.body, mysprites.WIDTH, mysprites.HEIGHT);
mysprites.director.makeMobileWebAppCapable();

var gamescene = new lime.Scene;

layer = new lime.Layer();
gamescene.appendChild(layer);

// load the spritesheet
mysprites.ss = new lime.SpriteSheet('assets/spaceman.png',lime.ASSETS.spaceman.json,lime.parser.JSON);

var sprite = mysprites.makeMonster().setPosition(100,100);
layer.appendChild(sprite);

//move
var moveRight = new lime.animation.MoveTo(874, 100)
    .setSpeed(1)
    .setEasing(lime.animation.Easing.LINEAR);

var moveLeft = new lime.animation.MoveTo(100, 100)
    .setSpeed(1)
    .setEasing(lime.animation.Easing.LINEAR);


// show animation
var anim = new lime.animation.KeyframeAnimation();
anim.delay= 1/10;
for(var i=0;i<=9;i++){
    anim.addFrame(mysprites.ss.getFrame('spaceman-'+'w'+'0'+i+'.png'));
}
monster.runAction(anim);

    var anim2 = new lime.animation.KeyframeAnimation();
anim.delay= 1/10;
for(var i=0;i<=9;i++){
    anim.addFrame(mysprites.ss.getFrame('spaceman-'+'e'+'0'+i+'.png'));
}
monster.runAction(anim2);

goog.events.listen(moveRight,lime.animation.Event.STOP, function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        monster.runAction(moveLeft);
    }, 500);
});

goog.events.listen(moveLeft,lime.animation.Event.STOP, function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        monster.runAction(moveRight);
    }, 500);
});   
};

mysprites.makeMonster = function(){
var sprite = new lime.Sprite().setPosition(200,200)
    .setFill(mysprites.ss.getFrame('spaceman-s00.png'));
//layer.appendChild(sprite);

return sprite;
};

goog.exportSymbol('mysprites.start', mysprites.start);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd better to ask your question here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/limejs
Please check the following things:

- If all the spritesheet items referenced in KeyframeAnimation are present in your spritesheet
- Try to use setDelay, setLooping API methods instead of direct assignment
- I do not see monster variable definition...